# Need help with Burnside's equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Theorem: Assume that $X$ is a $G$ set.

a) If $G$ acts transitively on $X$ and $x \in X$ then $[G:stab_G(x)]=|X|$
b) If  $R \subseteq X$ is a set of representatives of the G-orbits of $X$ then

$$|X|=\sum_{x \in R} [G:stab_G(x)]$$

I don't quite understand the premises

A G set is basically all the elements in the orbit of some $x$ right?. What is a G set?

a) This premise is basically saying that the number of left cosets or of St(x) equals the number of elements in the orbit of some x in the set which G acts on.

b) This is quite confusing because X is the set of elements of some orbit x, so This is saying the we can further divide up this set of elements of an orbit into more "orbit sets"

I need help with understanding this theorem.

Comment: a $G$ set is nothing but a set on which a group $G$ acts. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/G-Set.html

Comment: OHH OK. That's so refreshing cause the book doesn't define it explicitely

Comment: On the last posts, I have been receiving down votes for no reason. My posts fit perfectly the criteria of posting-rules of Math Stack Exchange. In my opinion, it's so annoying when someone does it for no reason. I feel like someone is doing this on purpose to "troll" my posts.

Comment: If somebody is having troubles with my posts, please point out the problem, otherwise I am not going to be able to improve the quality of my work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, orbits are those subsets of $X$ that are stable  under action of $G$, which basically means that elements of $G$ map the orbit to itself. $X$ is a disjoint union of these orbits (its a short lemma).Secondly, since the orbit consists of points of form $g.x$ for all elements of $g$ of $G$ and the action of $Stab(x)$ is trivial, we mod out action of $G$ by $Stab(x)$ which results in left cosets of $Stab(x$).